# Blackberry Code

Tags: blackberry, codesign, codesignkey

I have having difficulties protecting my blackberry application persistent data with ControlledAccess object.

According to http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/PersistentObject.html, I need a PersistentObject, CodeSignKey, and ControlledAccess objects to work. I have everything except one piece:

```
CodeSignKey codeSigningKey = CodeSigningKey.get( "ACME" );
```

here, I don't know what to replace for "ACME". Is this the PIN code I chose as I filled out the Code Sign Key? Is it my package name, output file name?

The Blackberry API documentation doesn't seem to say anything about this particularly important parameter.

Help please, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create your own key using the BlackBerry Signing Authority Tool.  See [this KB article](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/1295814/How_to_-_Protect_persistent_objects_from_access_by_unauthorized_applications.html?nodeid=2353703&vernum=0) for the full details.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's exactly what I needed. I thought the SignatureTool.jar was all I needed, but I realized that's for another purpose -- accessibility to the restricted RIM components.

Comment: By the way, do you know if the BB Flash memory is naturally encrypted. In case the handheld is stolen, how hard is it to dump the memory and brute force attack on it?

Comment: I have no idea about encryption but the flash memory is most likely surface-mounted onto the circuit board and it would be extremely hard to dump the memory.